# Unity: Set Gameobject active using if statement and collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, collider

I'm trying to set a game object active in my Unity 3D project (with Oculus SDK).

Hopefully this would be set active when the player collides with `triggerCube` (specifically want to be able to pick up `triggerCube` and then `ViewSight` `gameobject` is set active.

When player lets go, `ViewSight` `gameobject` is set to false.

I've tried turning off `ViewSight` `gameobject` in the inspector but still having it in the hierarchy. It didn't work so I made a prefab of it and deleted it from the hierarchy (and pulled it in to the script in the inspector for the `triggerCube)` and it didn't work that way either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

This is the script I have and its attached to the triggerCube:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ViewFinderStateTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ViewSight;

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "triggerCube")
        {
            ViewSight.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("Active");

        }
        else
        {
            ViewSight.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Not Active");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the code not running?

Comment: Sorry just to give you more detail, the code builds with no issues. On the console it shows the debug.log "Not Active" correctly but when I collide it says Instanciating and then shoots the error ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null. So my object is never set active

Comment: You need to assign the value. There are literally thousands of duplicates of that error all pointing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that, I thought I had given it a value by naming GameObject and pulling the prefab into into the script in the inspector but I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: That is generally how that works, yes. But there are reasons that even that would fail (eg if the object is destroyed by another script).